# How to preserve the position of scrolled text when restarting an application in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview

My name is Yuriy, I am from Kazakhstan. I want to learn a little about the Kotlin programming language. I was making an application for Android something similar to a book. In my application, I wanted to implement loading a book from the assets folder and displaying it on the screen. I also implemented vertical text scrolling.
It came down to saving the position of the scrolled text. But I am unable to save the scrolled text position when restarting the application. But I don’t understand how to do this correctly. Perhaps you friends can help me implement saving scrolled text when restarting the application. And if possible, point out the mistakes I made.

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ScrollView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader

@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
private lateinit var textBook: TextView


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Включаем функцию enableEdgeToEdge, чтобы приложение занимало всю доступную область экрана
        enableEdgeToEdge()

        // Устанавливаем содержимое экрана
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Инициализируем `TextView` с помощью `findViewById`
        textBook = findViewById(R.id.textViewBook)

        // Инициализируем `ScrollView` с помощью `findViewById`
        //val scrollView = findViewById<ScrollView>(R.id.myScrollView)

        // Устанавливаем слушатель изменения размеров окна для получения информации о системных панелях
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            // Получаем информацию о системных панелях и добавляем соответствующие отступы к View
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }




        //объявляем вне блока try, что позволяет ей быть доступной для использования в любом месте вашего кода.
        var text = ""

        // Открываем файл "book.txt" из ассетов и читаем его построчно
        // В этом коде мы обернули весь код, который работает с файлом,
        // в блок try-catch. Если при открытии файла или чтении его содержимого
        // возникнет исключение, мы его перехватим и выведем сообщение об ошибке
        // с помощью метода e.printStackTrace(). Это поможет нам понять,
        // что пошло не так, и исправить проблему.
        try {
            val inputStream = this.assets.open("book.txt")
            val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
            reader.use {
                var line: String?
                while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                    // Добавляем каждую строку к переменной text
                    text += line + "\n"
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            // Обрабатываем исключение
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        // Устанавливаем text\_view.text = text, чтобы отобразить текст на экране
        textBook.text = text







        // Добавляем прокрутку вверx, низ к textBook
        // textBook.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()




           // val prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
           // val editor = prefs.edit()
            //editor.putInt("scrollPosition", scrollView.scrollY)
           // editor.apply()
           //scrollView.scrollTo(0, prefs.getInt("scrollPosition", 0))


    }


    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        val prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = prefs.edit()
        editor.putInt("scrollPosition", textBook.scrollY)
        editor.apply()
    }





 override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
     super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
     val prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
     textBook.scrollTo(0, prefs.getInt("scrollPosition", 0))
 }



}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <!-- Это корневой ConstraintLayout, который содержит все остальные элементы -->


<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/myScrollView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <!-- Это ScrollView, который позволяет прокручивать содержимое, когда оно слишком большое -->
<TextView
android:id="@+id/textViewBook"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_book"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
    </ScrollView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I tried saving scrolled text like this

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putInt("scrollPosition", textBook.scrollY)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        textBook.scrollTo(0, savedInstanceState.getInt("scrollPosition"))
    }
```

SO

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    val prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = prefs.edit()
    editor.putInt("scrollPosition", textBook.scrollY)
    editor.apply()
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    val prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
    textBook.scrollTo(0, prefs.getInt("scrollPosition", 0))
}
```

AND

```
  val prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
           val editor = prefs.edit()
           editor.putInt("scrollPosition", scrollView.scrollY)
           editor.apply()
          scrollView.scrollTo(0, prefs.getInt("scrollPosition", 0))
```

Comment: I added a small check to the log. When closed, the data is saved. When opened, applications are loaded. But nothing happens. The text starts from the beginning. I don’t understand how to maintain the position correctly then. Here is the log file. Look, please tell mehttps://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eRqAT9jpRMtgqCLNY_i-ItABt3O6YGmbJzIHk_XRprM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems on the right track, however i've made some changes for better output.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ScrollView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader

private lateinit var textBook: TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        textBook = findViewById(R.id.textViewBook)

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        var text = ""
        try {
            val inputStream = this.assets.open("book.txt")
            val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
            reader.use {
                var line: String?
                while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                    text += line + "\n"
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        textBook.text = text

        // Restoring scroll position
        val prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
        textBook.scrollTo(0, prefs.getInt("scrollPosition", 0))
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        // Saving scroll position
        val prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = prefs.edit()
        editor.putInt("scrollPosition", textBook.scrollY)
        editor.apply()
    }
}
```

I moved the scroll position restoration code to the onCreate method after setting the text content. This ensures that the scroll position is restored when the activity is created.Also, the `textBook` variable is declared as `lateinit var` instead of `private lateinit var` at the top of your file, outside of the `onCreate` method. This is because you want to access it in other methods as well.

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: Hello, thanks, I tried your code now. But it also does not preserve the position in the text. If you simply minimize the application, the position of the scrolled text is preserved. And if you completely close the program and then open it, the text starts from the very beginning. maybe something needs to be added to the manifest file?

Comment: Code doesn`t work due to the lifecycle of the activity. Can you try setting the value under  onPostResume() method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem like this. Now the scrolling position is saved and restored.

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ScrollView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStreamReader


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Объявляем две переменные, которые будут использоваться в классе
    private lateinit var myScrollView: ScrollView
    private lateinit var textBook: TextView




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // Включаем функцию enableEdgeToEdge, чтобы приложение занимало всю доступную область экрана
        enableEdgeToEdge()

        // Устанавливаем макет activity\_main в качестве содержимого активности
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)



        // Находим элементы ScrollView и TextView   в макете
        myScrollView = findViewById(R.id.myScrollView)
        textBook = findViewById(R.id.textViewBook)




        // Добавляем слушатель для изменения отступов системы
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            // Получаем отступы системы и устанавливаем их как отступы для виджета
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }


        //объявляем text вне блока try, что позволяет ей быть доступной для использования в любом месте  кода.
        var text = ""

        // Читаем текст из файла "vatek.txt" и сохраняем его в переменной `text`
        try {
            val inputStream = this.assets.open("vatek.txt")
            val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
            reader.use {
                var line: String?
                while (reader.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                    text += line + "\n"
                }
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            // Обрабатываем исключение
            Log.e("MyApp", "Error reading file 'vatek.txt': ${e.message}")
        }

        // Устанавливаем текст из файла в TextView
        textBook.text = text



        // Получаем позицию прокрутки из SharedPreferences и прокручиваем ScrollView до этой позиции
        val prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
        val savedPosition = prefs.getInt("scrollPosition", 0)
        myScrollView.post {
            myScrollView.scrollTo(0, savedPosition)
        }

        // Проверяем, была ли восстановлена позиция прокрутки
        if (savedPosition != myScrollView.scrollY) {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Data not restored correctly Хз в чём дело")
        } else {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Data restored successfully")
        }

        // Устанавливаем слушатель для сохранения позиции прокрутки
        myScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener { v, _, _, _, _ ->
            Log.d("MyApp", "Saving scroll position  Сохранена позиция скролла")
            val editor = prefs.edit()
            editor.putInt("scrollPosition", v.scrollY)
            editor.apply()
        }


    }

    // Сохраняем позицию прокрутки при вызове метода onSaveInstanceState
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        // Saving scroll position
        val prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE)
        val savedPosition = prefs.getInt("scrollPosition", 0)
        if (savedPosition != myScrollView.scrollY) {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Data not saved correctly не корректно ")
        } else {
            Log.d("MyApp", "Data saved correctly по ходу дела")
        }
    }

}
```